# Smooth header scroll for both up and down

Tags: javascript, header

I've managed to get a smooth scroll function working on my site header (www.coreseven.media) when scrolling up the page, I'm wondering if it's possible for the same smooth transition to work when scrolling down? Now the header disappears instantly when scrolling down the page.

I'm guessing the code I used can work both ways?

JS code I've used:

```
jQuery ( function($) {

var tempscroll = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (scrollTop > tempscroll){ //Remove fixed positioning when scrolling down
      if ( $('.x-navbar-fixed-top').hasClass('x-navbar-fixed-top') ) $('.x-navbar-fixed-top').removeClass('x-navbar-fixed-top')
   } 
   tempscroll = scrollTop;

});

} );
```

CSS I've used:

```
.x-navbar{
    transition: transform ease 00ms;
    transform: translate3d(0px,0px, 0);
}

.x-navbar-fixed-top{
    transition: transform ease 600ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px, 29px, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease 600ms;

}
```

Comment: just wonder, how do you add `x-navbar-fixed-top` when scrolling back to top ?

Comment: Thanks for the reaction, and apologies for the late response!
To my knowledge, the theme I've used came with a sticky header option for which I've used the above JS code + CSS to animate the scroll. 

The standard functionality of the theme's sticky header is to just stay in position when scrolling down/up.